# what unit is used for the gas/gas limit in the ethereum/types lib?

Tags: go-ethereum, raw-transaction

I'm trying to create a raw transaction using [NewTransaction](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types#NewTransaction) send 1ETH to one transaction, set 21000 gasLimit(I understand this is fixed for any simple transaction) and set the gas price to 51 Gwei.

The issue I have is that there is no documentation about the unit used for Amount, gasLimit and gasPrice. Is it safe to use `big.NewInt(1)` (for 1ETH), `uint64(21000)` for gasLimit and `big.NewInt(51)` for gasPrice ?

```
NewTransaction(nonce uint64, to common.Address, amount *big.Int, gasLimit 
uint64, gasPrice *big.Int, data []byte) *Transaction
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is represented in Wei. Wei is the smallest unit of ethereum.
Gas limit (in your case 21000) is just 21000.
Gas price is represented in Gwei

```
1 Gwei = 10^9 Wei = 1,000,000,000 Wei
```

The amount to send in represented in Wei

```
1 Ether = 10^18 Wei = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 Wei
```

So for representing `5 ether` you can use `5*(10^18)` and for representing `50 Gwei` you can use `50*(10^9)` .

There are web3 methods to directly convert these units in [web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei).

Comment: So after all not everything is represented is Wei. The gas price is i n Gwei and the amount is in Wei.

Comment: The gas too is represented in Wei. But the gas price 51 is in Gwei. So if gas price is 50 then 50*(10^9) and if the amount is 5 ether then 5*(10^12). Hope this helps. If you need more detail I can edit the post and post a more detailed answer.

Comment: Is there any method function to do the conversion in Go ? web3 is a javascript sdk as far as I can see.

Comment: There is a 3rd party support code for accessing web3 using go lang. https://github.com/regcostajr/go-web3 Though I would recommend using the web3js which is officially supported.
You might also wanna check this https://godoc.org/github.com/jaynagpaul/go-web3

Comment: Just to be clear: gas itself is an abstract unit of work that exists inside the EVM - it doesn't have a unit of wei or ether. The _gas price_ has a unit of wei (or Gwei/ether).